# json.loads error with configParser value in Python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, configparser

I try to get a List from a config.ini file using JSON in python but when I use " ' " for the string value in my list I get an error. Surprisingly I don't have it when I use " " ".

Python Code :

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import json

#set and read the config file
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

#get the list with : ""
thisworks = json.loads(config.get('VALUES','value1'))
#get the list with : ''
thisnotwork = json.loads(config.get('VALUES','value2'))
```

config.ini file :

```
[VALUES]
value1 = ["tes1", "test2", "test3"]
value2 = ['tes1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

The variable "thisnotwork" return this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\Desktop\Nouveau dossier (2)\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    thisnotwork = json.loads(config.get('VALUES','value2'))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
[Finished in 0.258s]
```

<strike>This can be annoying because json.dumps() return 'string' and not "string"</strike>. If someone has a solution for this it can be really helpful.

Comment: I would expect the storing of `json` in your files to work. So, in what way does: `json.dumps() returns 'string' and not "string"`? When I do: `value2 = ['tes1', 'test2', 'test3']; json.dumps(value2)` I get: `["tes1", "test2", "test3"]`. I expect at some point you did: `config['VALUES']['value2'] = str(value2)`.

Comment: What not have the `config.ini` file consistent? with only double quotes.

Comment: @quamrana you right, i updated this

Comment: There is no way round this. If you want `json` data in your `ini` file, then the best way is to use `json.dump()` to generate the string for you when writing, then `json.loads()`, as you already have, will always work. There is the option of using a `try: except:` to discard invalid data.

Comment: @quamrana thanks, you resolve my problem. It's simple version of a more complex script. But my problem is because i .dumps() dictionnary of list and it's why the quote don't set the right way on the list. now it's ok.

Comment: Just to be clear: `json.dumps()` using any valid value **always** formats **any** strings inside double quotes. Because its part of the `json` standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSON Specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) requires double quotes to be used for string values.
I tried `json.dumps(['foo', 'bar'])` and it outputs double quotes as expected.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: https://www.json.org/json-en.html it's the info i missed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change the single quotations in `config.ini` list to double quotations like below:

```
value2= ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
f'''"value2" : {str(value2).replace("'", '"')},\n'''
```

with the output of

```
value2= ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
```